# Can I have an InnoDB master and MyISAM slaves with Full-Text for searching?

Tags: mysql, replication, innodb, myisam, full-text-search

I'd like to use InnoDB on the master, for its transactional ability, but MyISAM on the slaves for the full-text search ability. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Absolutely !!!

Just run `ALTER TABLE tblname ENGINE=MyISAM;` against all tables on the Slave that you want to have the FULLTEXT index. Afterwards, you can run `ALTER TABLE tblname ADD FULLTEXT (column[,column]);`.

Please be very careful not to run DDL against those tables in the Master that are unique to InnoDB that will replicate to the Slave.

I have suggested using a different Storage Engine on a Slave in my past posts:

- `Jun 01, 2011` : [What can we do in MySQL 5.0 Replication to address bandwidth concerns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3106/what-can-we-do-in-mysql-5-0-replication-to-address-bandwidth-concerns/3107#3107)
- `Nov 16, 2011` : [Log MySQL DB changing queries and users](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7985/log-mysql-db-changing-queries-and-users/7987#7987)
- `Mar 13, 2012` : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14943/setting-up-mysql-across-a-series-of-production-servers/14945#14945

Comment: Good news! You are the man Rolando.

Comment: It works great, I have a syslog system, where the master collects data into the BLACKHOLE storage engine, which then off-loads all the heavy lifting to the slave running combinations of MyISAM and InnoDB. This way I can pause the slave in order to analyse the data, leaving the master collecting and only using log storage :)